# Google API OAuth scopes

Tags: google-drive, google-oauth2

Есть ссылка:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&scope=profile drive&redirect_uri...
```

И немного непонятно со `scope`. При запросе `profile` все идет хорошо, но я так-же хочу доступ к диску и пишу `drive` но получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в консоли гугла эти скопы включены:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я не указывал сам `scope` правильно. Это, конечно, было очевидно, но не очень очевидно было то, что там через пробел нужно было указывать непосредственно URL того или иного `scope`.

```
...?response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&...
```

А еще смутило то, что при указании: `scope=profile` все работало.